# Will inbound international travel be affect by the latest lockdown?

Tags: uk

There is a new [month-long lockdown in England](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-54763956) that is expected to be announced shortly.

[It has also been reported that](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/10/31/travel-corridor-update-cyprus-quarantine-restrictions-news/):

> Outbound international travel will be banned.

Will inbound international travel be affected during the duration of this new lockdown?

Comment: You may have to wait till the new lockdown has been officially announced and the details worked out. But you can expect air traffic to be much more restricted. (Likely not completely stopped but that is possible.)

Comment: It would be also interesting to see if EU flights are going to be affected. For example France banned international flights, but allows the ones from and to EU countries. Note: the "It has also been reported that" link to Telegraph requires me to pay/sign up/or something else that I don't want to do either, in order to be able to view the contents tnx for putting the interesting part in the question.

Comment: If Ireland doesn't follow suit, you could probably fly to Dublin and take the bus/drive to Northern Ireland, then take a ferry to England.

Answer (score 5):

No it won't. [As per this analysis by the Independent:](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/international-travel-ban-uk-four-week-lockdown-b1482052.html)

> There is no impact on inbound travel, though of course existing quarantine rules apply.

> Assuming you are returning to the UK during lockdown, there is a good chance that your flight will operate as normal.

> However, the ban on international travel means that airlines and holiday companies are likely to cut back services to reduced their losses.

Comment: Although I believe we should wait for Monday and the government website gets updated, since British won't update the critical info on a weekend...